# Bull/Bear/Flat Market mathematical definition

Tags: market-data, algorithmic-trading

I need to label historical dataset by market type and look for automated solution. I have couple related questions.

1. Maybe there some ready solutions that I was not able to find?
2. Is there some price change percentage range which is commonly accepted as "bull", "bear" and "flat" market? Does it depend on asset pair? If so, what are they for BTCUSD?
3. Should the price change be averaged by amount of last candles? How do I figure out how many candles I should take?

Comment: The general definition of a market **correction** is a market decline that is more than 10%, but less than 20%. A **bear** market is usually defined as a decline of 20% or greater from recent highs. I'd classify a **"flat"** as + / - 5%. A **bull** market would then be market rallying by more than 5%.

Comment: To add to what @JanStuller said: these % changes are for equity markets where long-term realised vol is ~20%. I would take that into account for BTC where long-term realised vol is much higher.